# Javascript Collision Issues

Tags: javascript

I have a ball bouncing around the screen and I need to write code that essentially ends the game when it collides with the player... This is my current code, but it isn't working. Let me know if you need more information.

```
if(playerLoc == ballLoc){
       gameOver();
       }
```

Where playerLoc/ballLoc are measured based of X and Y axis measurements.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    //get info, process data, update screen objects
        //instance vars
        var player;
        var ball;
        var score;
        var axis;
        var ballaxis;
        //initial speeds
        var dx = 6;
        var dy = 6;
        var currentScore = 0;
        var timer;
        //set initial conditions for ball and paddle

        var playerTop = 400;
        var playerLeft = 200;
        var ballLeft = 228;
        var ballTop = 4;
        var playerLoc = playerLeft + playerTop;
        var ballLoc = ballLeft + ballTop;

        function init(){
            //instantiate HTML object instance vars
            player = document.getElementById('player');
            ball = document.getElementById('ball');
            score = document.getElementById('score');
            axis = document.getElementById('axis');
            ballaxis = document.getElementById('ballaxis');
            //register key listener with document object
            document.onkeydown = keyListener;
            //start the game loop
            start();

        }

        function keyListener(e){
            if(!e){
                //for IE
                e = window.event;
            }
            if(e.keyCode==37 && playerLeft > 0){
                //keyCode 37 is left arrow
                playerLeft -= 10;
                player.style.left = playerLeft + 'px';
            }
            if(e.keyCode==39 && playerLeft < 450){
                //keyCode 39 is right arrow
                playerLeft += 10;
                player.style.left = playerLeft + 'px';
            }
            if(e.keyCode==38 && playerTop > 0){
                //keyCode 38 is up arrow
                playerTop -= 10;
                player.style.top = playerTop + 'px';
            }
            if(e.keyCode==40 && playerTop < 450){
                //keyCode 40 is down arrow
                playerTop += 10;
                player.style.top = playerTop + 'px';
            }
        }

        function start(){
            //game loop
            render();
            detectCollisions();
            difficulty();
            axisMeasure();

            //end conditions

            if(playerLoc == ballLoc){
                gameOver();
                }
            else{
                //still in play - keep the loop going
                timer = setTimeout('start()',50);   
            }

        }



        function detectCollisions(){
            //just reflect the ball on a collision
            //a more robust engine could change trajectory of ball based
            //on where the ball hits the paddle
            if(collisionX())
                dx = dx * -1;
            if(collisionY())
                dy = dy * -1;
        }

        function collisionX(){
            //check left and right boundaries
            if(ballLeft < 2 || ballLeft > 480)
                return true;

            else {
                return false;   
            }

        }

        function collisionY(){
            //check if at top of playing area
            if(ballTop < 2  || ballTop > 480)
                return true;

            else {
                return false;
            }    

        }

        function render(){
            moveBall();
            updateScore();
        }

        function moveBall(){
            ballLeft += dx;
            ballTop += dy;
            ball.style.left = ballLeft;
            ball.style.top = ballTop;
        }

        function axisMeasure(){
            axis.innerHTML = 'P X-Axis: ' + playerLeft + ' P Y-Axis:   ' + playerTop
            ballaxis.innerHTML = 'B X-Axis: ' + ballLeft + ' B Y-Axis:   ' + ballTop        
        }

        function updateScore(){
            currentScore += 5;
            score.innerHTML = 'Score: ' + currentScore;
        }

        function difficulty(){
            //as the game progresses, increase magnitude of the vertical speed
            if(currentScore % 1000 == 0){
                if(dy > 0)
                    dy += 1;
                else
                    dy -= 1;
            }
        }

        function gameOver(){
            //end the game by clearing the timer, modifying the score label
            clearTimeout(timer);
            score.innerHTML += "   Game Over";
            score.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(128,0,0)';
```

Comment: "More information"? You didn't tell us anything... What are those `playerLoc`, `ballLoc` and `gameOver`? When is this snippet executed?

Comment: Please share all your code. That amount of code is not sufficient to be able to answer this question.

Comment: We would need more information.  Is your playerloc an object or a variable?  Is the variable unpdated real time?

Comment: Have you looked into collision detection routines? If so you will realize that 1 pixel is not a large enough detection area.

Comment: technically this code does work, you have just never seen the instance of when it is working because youre looking for top left pixel of ball to be equal to top left pixel of player...

Comment: also why tag it with html and css, ok so maybe you use it in your other code but your example and what youre asking for has nothing to do with either...

Comment: Jeez guys, chill out. I've had this up for like 20 min. Kinda new at this.

Comment: Just summing up X and Y values to a single value (your player~/ballLoc) won't work either. You'll never know the exact position, just the possible area, the specific point can be. So comparison of your *Loc's will give you a lot of false positives.

Comment: What would be a better way to work this situation then?

Comment: Just use the provided answer, these checks will work (I would prefer the distance method).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lol.. well you have like no code shown. So this is a *complete* shot in the dark.

```
if(playerLoc.x == ballLoc.x && playerLoc.y == ballLoc.y){
       gameOver();
}
```

OR, even try the distance method.

```
var distance = Math.sqrt((ballLoc.x- playerLoc.x) *(ballLoc.x-playerLoc.x) + (ballLoc.y - playerLoc.y) * (ballLoc.y-playerLoc.y));

if(distance < *some amount*)}
       gameOver();
}
```

[Also heres a live demo of the distance check in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/87q39/)

**Edit**

Ok well now that the code is posted, my answer is somewhat irrelevant, but Ill keep it here regardless since the distance check is a valid method that would even work in the OP's case.

```
var ballX = ballLeft + (ballWidth/2),
    ballY = ballTop + (ballHeight/2),
    playerX = playerLeft + (playerWidth/2),
    playerY = playerTop + (playerHeight/2);

var distance = Math.sqrt((ballX - playerX) *(ballX - playerX) + (ballY - playerTop) * (ballY - playerTop )); 
if(distance < 25){ gameOver(); }
```

Comment: thats detecting collission of 1 pixel touching 1 pixel, the chances of that happening are well, pretty slim...

Comment: Yeah I know, but we have no idea what the guys code looks like, figured Id give him something to mess with, also thats why I added the distance check method which would work out better anyway.

Comment: He would be better off starting with treating both as large squares and seeing if any part of one is equal to the location of any part of another

Comment: @RhysW I disagree since he mentions balls, checking the distance will provide close to perfect collision conditions.

Comment: i agree i meant for your first example, youre second example i have no fault with!

Comment: You can improve this by using the distance squared instead of calling an unnecessary `Math.sqrt`. But then again, we need more details from Akbip.

Comment: I would assume it would be easier If I could measure the squares of both the player and the ball that colide instead of one pixel in each.

Comment: var distance = Math.sqrt((ballLoc.x- playerLoc.x) *(ballLoc.x-playerLoc.x) + (ballLoc.y - playerLoc.y) * (ballLoc.y-playerLoc.y));
   
   if(distance < 25){
          gameOver();
   }

I must be misunderstanding this. This is what I have and it isn't working.

Comment: @Akbip check out my edit, ball.x would be ballLeft, ball.y would be ballTop, the same for the player.

Comment: @Loktar It sort of works now. GameOver() will happen when the ball hits the player's horizontal score. However, it needs to match both the horizontal and vertical score for a game over.

Comment: Got it. 

var distance = Math.sqrt((ballLeft - playerLeft) *(ballLeft - playerLeft) + (ballTop - playerTop) * (ballTop - playerTop)); 
   if(distance < 58){ gameOver(); }

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Akbip well that will have some issues too I wasnt thinking straight, top, and left.. are top and left. The distance check assumes the collision point starts in the middle. So for that to work corrently do, ballLeft + (width/2), ballTop + (height/2), and the same for player. I reedited my answer. Anyway glad it works :).

Comment: It would look like this then?

var distance = Math.sqrt((ballLeft + (width/2) - playerLeft) *(ballLeft - playerLeft) + (ballTop + (width/2) - playerTop) * (ballTop - playerTop)); if(distance < 58){ gameOver(); }